# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined after publish the application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Before publish it works fine but when i publish and run it give me an error
called - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined . I am using these .js at my Master Page .

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/chrome.js"></script>
<%-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.simplyscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.simplyscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/coin-slider.min.js"></script>
```

Visual Studio 2010 - running in IE9 IE8 Google crome. Any advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know it's not connected to the question, but I will advice to use higher version of jQuery - what you will gain with two words is "better performance".

Comment: Are you sure these are the correct paths for your jQueries? Do you want to use absolute uris and try?

Comment: TJ i have also tried with the the absolute  src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript" but not workes

Comment: It seems you are loading jQuery twice. Try loading it once only.

Comment: Yes Daniel is right you load it there : <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.js"></script> and there : <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yep that's most likely the answer - double loading of jquery can cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>')</script>
```

This is the use Google's hosted jQuery, but on Google fail, you can fall back to your hosted library. Please try to use the latest jquery [*Current Release*: **v1.8.3**]. You can get it from [here](http://jquery.com/).